# Py4JJavaError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.ParentNotDirectoryException error in Spark on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, pyspark

I am currently working on a Spark application on my MacOS Monterey 12.5.1 machine in a clean Python virtual environment, but I keep running into an issue when attempting to write a file using Spark's DataFrameWriter. I'm using PySpark version 3.3.1 and Python 3.9.16.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
spark_dataframe.coalesce(1).write.csv(
    output_filepath,
    mode=mode,
    compression=compression,
    sep="\t" if tsv else ",",
    header=False,
    escape='"',
)
```

The error message I'm receiving is:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o213.csv.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.ParentNotDirectoryException: Parent path is not a directory: file:/path/to/my/data_file.tsv.gz
```

Here's what I've checked so far:

1. The directory /path/to/my/ is valid and exists.
2. I have the correct permissions to access this directory.
3. The exact same code works without any issues on an Ubuntu machine.

I'm at a loss as to why this is occurring. Any help in troubleshooting this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you define this `data_file.tsv.gz` file in the configuration? is this the input or the output or something else?

Comment: It is the ouput, passed to spark writer via `output_filepath`.

Comment: I think this is the issue, you need to pass a directory not a file, then Spark will create the output files under this dir